# Error in Maven building?

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

After i wrote

```
mvn -f pom.xml compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=Compile-Dexec.main Class=storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

and found this !!

> [INFO] One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for
>   'exec:java'
>
> [0] Inside the definition for plugin 'exec-maven-plugin' specify the
>   following:
>
> ... VALUE
>
> -OR-
>
> on the command line, specify: '-Dstorm.topology=VALUE

Comment: try mvn -f pom.xml compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="Compile" -Dexec.mainClass="storm.starter.WordCountTopology"

Comment: @sasanked i tried it but still the same error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you link your pom.xml then this would be easier. I'm guessing you're using [Storm](http://storm-project.net/). Have you written your own `topologyClass`? From [the documentation](https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md):

> topologyClass
>
> The class name of the topology driver (e.g. "com.foo.bar.MyTopology")
>   Command line override: -Dmaven.storm.topology=

The documentation also gives you the code for your pom but you might want to add exec-maven-plugin to your pom.xml like so:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.domain.yourApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

One thing to note: ***you need to alter `mainClass` to match the class in your project that contains the main method you want to execute.***

Then you can just run `mvn exec:java`.

Comment: I'm new in storm and trying to submit already written topology in storm starter file called WordCountTopology .here in the link my pom.xml file http://www.2shared.com/document/yZPU74go/pom.html

Comment: I don't use Storm but try: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="storm.starter.WordCountTopology`

Comment: Or try the two commands listed here:

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter#running-topologies-with-maven

`mvn -f m2-pom.xml compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.WordCountTopology`

 OR 

`mvn -f m2-pom.xml compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.clj.word_count`

Comment: It's odd you're getting the same error since you are now specifying `storm.topology`. It should be a different error at least :P

Comment: Sorry, I don't use storm. Have you tried the google groups forum?
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/storm-user

Comment: i'll try now .. but i guess that i'll find anyone here help me faster Thanks @ porcoesphino